# GNOME Terminal lost CSD after installing XFCE

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, csd

I was trying XFCE 4.14 on Ubuntu 20.04, just to see how it was. After that, I've completed removed it and all it's packages and came back to GNOME shell.
Suddenly, I realized that the New Tab "+" icon and Search icon were gone from the title bar.
This is how it looks like now
[image]

Before, the title bar looked like this (image from internet, so it has a different theme)
[image]

How to I get my title bar back the way it used to be?
PS: I can't find an option to revert thins on "preferences" windows from GNOME Terminal

Comment: is this the ```gnome-terminal``` or ```xfce4-terminal```?

Comment: gnome-terminal. xfce4-terminal is not installed anymore. double checked it

Comment: For the future, please note that adding / removing desktop environments *may* have unpredictable effects. BTW, what does `apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep -i nocsd` show?

Comment: apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep -i nocsd showed nothing.... tried with and without sudo

Comment: Great you solved your problem. The command I mentioned doesn't require `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

I GOT IT!! Found an option in dconf-editor. Navigating to /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar and changed the value to "true"

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer! That hints other users that the solution is there.